# WebSocket connection not establish using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

This is Used for Thermal Printing, When I run the application it shows followings Error in Console :

> jquery.websocket.js:45 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send'
>   on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.

Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function connect() {
         debugger;
         var ws = new WebSocket("wss://192.168.1.23:9100");
         ws.onopen = function () {
             alert("About to send data");
             ws.send("Hello World"); // I WANT TO SEND THIS MESSAGE TO THE SERVER!!!!!!!!
             alert("Message sent!");
         };

         ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
             alert("About to receive data");
             var received_msg = evt.data;
             alert("Message received = " + received_msg);
         };
         ws.onclose = function () {
             // websocket is closed.
             alert("Connection is closed...");
         };
     };


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with your code and seems it's working.Can you please check the same with 'wss://echo.websocket.org' url from your side? 
I have referred https://www.websocket.org/echo.html url . Below is the same code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To test web socket</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function connect() {
                debugger;
                var ws = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org");
                ws.onopen = function () {
                    alert("About to send data");
                    ws.send("Hello World"); // I WANT TO SEND THIS MESSAGE TO THE SERVER!!!!!!!!
                    alert("Message sent!");
                };

                ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                   alert("About to receive data");
                   var received_msg = evt.data;
                   alert("Message received = " + received_msg);
                };
                ws.onclose = function () {
                    // websocket is closed.
                   alert("Connection is closed...");
                };
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <button onclick="connect()">Connect</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but I specified how to get them with local IP address(thermal printer), when code run on server(online).